# Custom Post Type con Post asignados

Tags: wordpress, post

Necesito tener en la administración una opción llamada "Instituciones Educativas" y por eso he creado un CPT llamado "ie" pero no debe quedar con URL, es decir debe quedar siempre wwww.misitio.com/institucion-educativa-wordpress y no wwww.misitio.com/ie/institucion-educativa-wordpress .

Cuando el administrador ingrese al CPT "Instituciones Educativas" va a crear los respectivas Instituciones con su información, algo así como el despliegue de cada institución pero adicionalmente necesitan notas editoriales que pertenecen a ese CPT, es decir debe quedar asi : wwww.misitio.com/institucion-educativa-wordpress/nota-editorial-sobre-wordpress .

Seria como añadir la funcionalidad de Post dentro de un Custom Post Type, lo pienso como :

- Instituciones Educativas

  - Añadir nueva Institución
  - Notas Editoriales

    - Añadir Nueva Nota Editorial
    - Categorías
    - Tags
  - Categorías
  - Tags

No estoy seguro de que se pueda hacer, sin embargo puede que si.

Answer (score 1):

Según parece necesitas que tu custom post type "Instituciones Educativas" se relacione con "algo" llamado "Notas Editoriales" de manera que se pueda acceder  a la url "misitio.com/nombre-de-la-institucion/nombre-de-la-nota-editorial". Supongo que al tener el custom type desarrollado, tendras la plantilla que los muestra también, junto con el loop de consulta.

A partir de aquí, falta relacionar las "Notas editoriales" con la "Institución Educativa" correspondiente, supongo que de forma que cada "Institución Educativa" tenga desde cero a muchas "Notas editoriales".

Una posible solución sería crear otro custom type para las "Notas Editoriales" que tenga un custom field llamado "Intitución Educativa" que sea del tipo desplegable y que permita seleccionar una institución que ya exista en el sistema. De forma que al almacenar el custom type  "Nota Editorial" se almacene junto al qué "Institución Educativa" pertenece.

Por último sólo faltaría modificar el loop de consulta de las "Instituciones Educativas" para que consulten todos los post del tipo "Nota Editorial" que tengan un campo llamado de la misma manera que el nombre de la "Institución Educativa" que estamos consultando.

Answer (score 1):

@pio lo único que se me ocurre (soy nueva en WordPress) es una estructura de este estilo (parto de la premisa que instituciones educativas está dentro de un index.php) : Una página llamada Instituciones Educativas con su correspondiente plantilla php. En esa plantilla, colocas el código que sea necesario que lleve instituciones. Después, creas otra página llamada Añadir nueva institución (con su correspondiente plantilla) y a esta la haces hija de la anterior (Instituciones educativas). También haces otra página Notas Editoriales (siempre con su correspondiente plantilla php) que es hija de Instituciones Educativas y hermana de Añadir nueva institución. Ahora yo veo 2 opciones, dependiendo de lo que quieras: La primera es que en el código de Notas Editoriales enlaces los posts creados con el CPT-UI y el Custom Advanced Fields mediante loops y querys. Con esta opción en la misma página de Notas Editoriales, tendrías los 3 campos (dentro de ello, siendo la misma página). Ahora, si lo que quieres es que cada una de esas opciones vaya a otra página, sería repetir el mismo proceso: Crear las tres páginas (añadir nueva nota editorial, categorías y tags) que sean hermanas entre si pero hijas de Notas Editoriales. Haciéndolo de esta manera, la URL incluiría la sección.

Después, para la Categorías y tags que no van dentro de Notas editoriales, lo harías haciendo dos páginas hijas de instituciones educativas, hermanas de añadir nueva institución y notas editoriales (y hermanas entre si claro).

Te dejo una imagen de como sería la jerarquía con las propias páginas, de dónde cuelga cada una etc (en una sección no puse que son hermanas porque no se leería bien y causaría confusiones pero se entiende que lo son).

Con los posts del CPT-UI + Custom Advanced Files irías añadiendo la información de cada sección en la página correspondiente y luego mediante loops etc de WordPress mostrando la información.

[image: Jerarquia paginas]

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda, no me llego esta notificación pero lo resolví similar a la indicación.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré otra solución muy practica vía: https://1fix.io/blog/2016/02/05/parent-from-another-cpt/.

Es increíble y funciona mejor por que permite manejar cada custom post type sin relacionarlo a través de un plugin.

Comment: ¿Podrías mencionar las características principales encontradas en el enlace que publicaste? Un enlace podría no estar disponible en el futuro. Además, siguiendo el formato de [es.so], se esperan respuestas completas dentro de la publicación.